# Creating a function in VBA that has a dynamic array for an argument and its output is also a dynamic array

Tags: arrays, vba, dynamic

Here's what I'm trying to do:
Suppose that you have a dynamic array whose dimensions can be from **0x6** up to **10x6** (meaning we can have rows anywhere from 0 to 10, but columns are always 6). I have been desperately trying to create a function (and then bind it to a macro) that will use as argument this first array, and will create a second array as output, whose elements will be the returns of the first array. For example, if we have the simple case of 1x6, then the output array's elements are five and in each case are given by the formula `(x_i+1 - x_i)/x_i, i=1, 2, ..., 6`. Additionally, the function must be able to bypass any missing values from the input array and ignore the corresponding non-existent return values. The entire thing must be done in VBA script.

It's been two days since I have been searching frantically for some help, but the problem is that I have no idea whatsoever about programming in VBA (I usually use other languages like MATLAB or Mathematica) so this is extremely hard for me. Any solutions that I have found I wasn't able to put together and achieve my goal. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because you provided no code, I cannot determine exactly what you want to do, but here is an example of passing an array and returning an array that you should be able to extrapolate.

Edit: Just for fun,  updated this to work for up to 3 dimensional arrays.

```
Public Sub Test()
    'Defines testArray as Variant 0 to 10
    Dim testArray(0 To 1, 0 To 6) As Long
    Dim returnArray() As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Debug.Print UBound(testArray, 2)
    'Populates testArray with Longs
    For i = 0 To UBound(testArray, 1)
        For j = 0 To UBound(testArray, 2)
            testArray(i, j) = (i + j) * 2
        Next
    Next
    'Passes testArray and returns ParseArray
    returnArray = addOne(testArray)
  End Sub

Public Function addOne(arrValues() As Long) As Variant
    Dim arrCopy() As Long
    Dim dimensionNum As Long, ErrorCheck As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    For dimensionNum = 1 To 60000
        ErrorCheck = LBound(arrValues, dimensionNum)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            dimensionNum = dimensionNum - 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    'Copies passed array to avoid updating passed array directly
    arrCopy = arrValues
    'Adds 1 to each element of the array.
    If dimensionNum = 1 Then
        For i = LBound(arrCopy) To UBound(arrCopy)
            arrCopy(i) = arrCopy(i) + 1
        Next
    ElseIf dimensionNum = 2 Then

        For i = LBound(arrCopy) To UBound(arrCopy)
            For j = LBound(arrCopy, 2) To UBound(arrCopy, 2)
                arrCopy(i, j) = arrCopy(i, j) + 1
            Next
        Next
    ElseIf dimensionNum = 3 Then
        For i = LBound(arrCopy) To UBound(arrCopy)
            For j = LBound(arrCopy, 2) To UBound(arrCopy, 2)
                For k = LBound(arrCopy, 3) To UBound(arrCopy, 3)
                    arrCopy(i, j, k) = arrCopy(i, j, k) + 1
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "Add function only works for three dimensions or fewer arrays"
    End If
    addOne = arrCopy
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your code did help to understand a few things. but unfortunately I wasn't able to solve my problem in the end. If you feel like it, I can send you the original excel file (which is no bigger than 20kb) and you can take a look at the problem yourself. In any case, thank you very much for the quick reply.

Comment: I suppose that would make sense... my answer doesn't really address your entire issue, it's just a tip as to how you can pass arrays between functions.